# Twitter queries using regexp?

Tags: regex, twitter

I have been seeing posts and questions about using regexp to search for tweets on twitter using the java twitter API. Now, I have been trying to do that for the last two hours reading all possible resources on that with no success. For example: I am simply trying to query twitter once, but receive the tweets for both "guerillacafe" or "guerilla cafe"

I have tried (guerillacafe|guerilla cafe), ('guerillacafe'|'guerilla cafe'), (guerillacafe OR guerilla cafe), (guerilla?cafe) and many more, but like I said , I cant get it to work.

Please help with a simple regexp that would do the trick.

Comment: It seems unlikely that's possible as it would be a gargantuan data task on Twitter's side. Have you got any sources?
Twitter's native search supports:
guerillacafe OR "guerilla cafe"

Comment: well, I cant say that's the first time it happens to me, but I was sure I tried the OR thing and it didnt work before, but now that you said it, I decided to try it again, and what do you know... it works!

Answer (score 0):

The Java Twitter API does not allow for regexp searches. The `OR` keyword is supported (your third example works for me).